# Add more "executors" to an agent

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops

We're actively moving from Jenkins to Azure Devops.

In Jenkins you create `Nodes` which have `Executors`, this essentially makes a physical machine capable of running jobs (or `stages` to be specific) in parallel equal to the number of allowed `Executors` on the given `Node`.

However, in Azure Devops, I cannot find anything equivalent of this.
As far as I understand, a `Pool` is a group of machines? Where each machine is an `Agent`.

For example, we have a high-end windows machine, where we want it to be able to run 12 jobs in parallel, like you can in Jenkins. Is it possible to get the same functionality in Azure Devops?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSTS build agents - Can one computer run multiple build agents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40797253/vsts-build-agents-can-one-computer-run-multiple-build-agents)

Comment: consult the answer linked, thats the way to do it in ADO

Comment: @riQQ Yes thank you! I tried searching, but I had very little knowledge about what to search for, since the terminology is completely different.